# Solidity error: require: ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('

Tags: solidity, remix

has someone knows what should be fixed on the below Solidity code?

```
require (_value%100 == 0);
uint fee = _value/1000; // for 1% fee
require (balanceOf[msg.sender] > _value) ;
require (balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
balanceOf[_to] += (_value-fee);
balanceOf[thirdPartyAddress] += value;
```

I'm currently using the solidity 4.26 and this is showing the following error: ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(' require (_value%100 == 0); ^

Any comment is welcomed :)

Comment: Hi there. Is this code inside a function? Can you please edit your question to include all the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say, given that you haven't included all of the code.

It *looks* like the above code hasn't been written inside a function...

Once that's fixed, there's also an error on this line:

```
balanceOf[thirdPartyAddress] += value;
```

`value` should be `_value`.

Comment: thanks a lot by your answer! This is the only piece of the code that is being accusing an error. Actually, error is happening only on the lines mentioning "require". Thanks in advance by the help!

Comment: Okay, thanks for the details. The error will be before the first require line, so we need to see the previous lines of code. Also, this code must be inside a function.